# Python.h linker error in Xcode

Tags: python, c++, ios, xcode

I am trying to use some Python in my Swift iOs App. So I am bridging between C++ and Swift (that works fine) to use Python.h in my cpp file. I read about Python.h and did the following to use it :

**1:** In the Build settings adjust my **Other C/C++ Flags** for the Path to the Python 2.7 Framework includes :
[image: Flags]

**2:** Post the following code in my **Translator.cpp** :

```
\#include < Python.h >
extern "C" void test()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

When compiling I get this error :

[image: Errors]

To my understanding that means that the Python 2.7 Framework I am trying to use, is not built for an x86_64 architecture. But what do I do to solve this problem. Note that I did not build this Python Framework - except from installing it.

Comment: You need to _link_ with Python as well. Imagine you're shown pieces of wood and asked to build a chair using them. But there's a wall made of thick glass between you and the wood, so you can actually do nothing with them. The same thing happens to the compiler: you show it the declarations of some functions, but don't give it the functions themselves.

Comment: Awesome ! I am amazed by your explanation skills ! Just wanted to throw that out there. I am now going to work on the execution of your advice =)

Comment: @ForceBru Ok I found this little technical note [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2328/_index.html). I tried embedding Python as Framework by dragging it into the Sidebar. I found it using _sudo find / -name "Python.framework"_ which gave me _/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework_ and _/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-migrator/sdks/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework_ I tried both but now I get the error  _ld: framework not found Python_